# Adding a second UIToolbar to a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

We have an app that uses UITableViewControllers (or subclasses of them) in many places, and we've just come up with a UI scenario which requires us to add a **second** UIToolbar above the built-in one that UINavigationController provides by default.

Ideally, we'd like to simply add a UIToolbar as a subview of the UITableViewController that needs it so that it appears in the bottom and the whole tableview just shrinks vertically by 44px, but it doesn't seem like it's possible to add another subview to the UITableViewController that would behave this way because `self.view == self.tableView` for UITableViewController.

We'd love to avoid ripping out every instance of UITableViewController and replacing it with some subclass of UIViewController that *contains* a UITableView and hooks up the datasource and delegate manually, simply because of the vast number of files it would touch to implement a relatively isolated feature.

Is there any more surgical way to achieve getting a second UIToolbar to appear at the bottom of a UITableViewController that we're not seeing?

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Which solution did you finally take?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing as you said and converting your `UITableViewController` to a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` as a subview. If you really don't want to do that there is one other method that will also work. Add the toolbar as a subview to your tableview and use the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method to change its offset to anchor it to the bottom. You can adjust the visible height of the tableview by changing its `contentInset` property.